# Does gcc 6 support the use of std::sample (c++17)?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, gcc6

I'm trying to compile this piece of **c++ 17** code that contains [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) using **gcc version 6.3.0** with the following command: `g++ -std=gnu++17 -c main.cpp`.

But I get this: `error: ‘sample’ is not a member of ‘std’`...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::vector<int> b(5);

    std::sample(a.begin(), a.end(), 
                b.begin(), b.size(),
                std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

    return 0;
}
```

Does gcc 6 support the use of `std::sample`? (It compiles fine with gcc 8.2.0)

I could not find the answer on this two pages:

- [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)
- [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: It compiles fine with MinGW g++ 7.3.0 That's a version you can use in Windows, if that's the problem.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017

Comment: FWIW, windows already has GCC 8.1 (MinGW-w64).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017 is the place to check. Answer (Which should be obvious): No.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Do you have a link, or are you talking about using a Linux environment such as Windows 10's WSL, and cross-compiling?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No, I'm not talking about using a Linux environment. [Here's the link.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html), but until [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) it is in `std::experimental` namespace and defined in `<experimental/algorithm>` header.

From GCC 5 Release notes:

> **Runtime Library (libstdc++)**
>
> - Improved experimental support for the Library Fundamentals TS, including:
>
>   - function template std::experimental::sample;

Tested on GCC 5.1 https://wandbox.org/permlink/HWnX3qSgKbZO2qoH

Answer (score 3):

No. We can see from the [table in the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017) under "Library Fundamentals V1 TS Components: Sampling" that the earliest version of libstdc++ to support `std::sample` is version 7.1

Answer (score 1):

> Does gcc 6 support the use of std::sample?

No. You need GCC 7. From the [GCC 7 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html):

> - Experimental support for C++17, including the following new features:
>
>   - ...
>   - std::sample, std::default_searcher, std::boyer_moore_searcher and
>       std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher;

For GCC 7 you may need `-std=c++1z` or `-std=gnu++1z` since it is experimental.